# Since when {could/can} he move so quick?

Tags: tense

**[SOURCE](http://www.thaisubtitle.com/manage/view_subtitle.php?mid=34055&start=201)**   *Attack on Titan*, 2013 Anime Season 2, Ep. 7

What is the difference between "Since when **could** he move so quick?" and "Since when **can** he move so quick?"

The original sentence is the version with **could**, but I'm wondering if it has the same meaning with **can**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both of these sentences are very linguistically incorrect.  A more correct expression would be something like:

> “Since when has he been able to move so quickly?”

In many cases, the answers to questions like yours are more obvious when the sentence is spoken or written correctly to begin with.

Comment: Given that the sentence was taken from an apparent battle scene in an action anime series, though, we don't expect the characters to speak in "linguistically correct" language. We expect them to talk like warriors on a battlefield. And your answer should also try to answer the question; namely, does the meaning of the original change if we use _can_ instead of _could_?

Answer (score 1):

The question refers to a moment in time which lies in the past, in relation to the moment that the question was asked:

> At which moment did he start being able to move so quickly?

would be equivalent in meaning to the orignal question.

> At which moment in time does he start being able to...

clearly doesn't make sense when referring to a moment in the past. That's the reason why **could** is semantically more correct then **can**, even though it's not as obvious when using this form.

On a sidenote: the adjective *quick* should be replaced by the adverb *quickly*.

Also note the comment by @p-e-dant, which mentions the use of the modal verb *could* to highlight a present ability/possibility. This is another possible interpretation, although I find it doesn't completely apply.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence using 'can',

> Since when can he move so quickly?

has an idiomatic meaning that expresses incredulity of the assertion. The speaker is saying that something has changed since they knew how quickly he could move. They doubt that it is actually the case that he can move so quickly because he was not able to move so quickly previously.

Some other examples of this usage might be

> Since when are you in charge?  John is the manager, not you.
> Since when do we serve people without a shirt and shoes? We've never done that before.
> Since when can she speak Spanish? The last I knew she only spoke French.

Answer (score -3):

`Could` is an obsolete past tense of the word `can`.  The words are roughly equivalent auxiliary verbs.  There is a shade of meaning in the word `could` that expresses doubt.

`It could be true.` as opposed to `It can be true.`

There is a difference between `Can I play poker?` and `Could I play poker?`

Comment: Really, B.W.? Where on Earth did you get the idea "Could is an obsolete past tense of the word can", please?

Comment: Downvoted because 'could' is not obsolete.